# Display the input when a specific option is selected in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am using **Laravel 5.2**. I have an input to display when a specific option is selected and it works fine.

But I want to use **{{ old('field') }}** to have the old results.

- When I select **Yes**, I have to display the input.
- When I select **No**, I have to hide the input.

When I have validation errors (server side) and I return to the page, then I have the old results (example: value='yes') but the input that was displaying is now hidden and I have to re-click on **yes** to display it again. I use the change event to display the input.

```
$("#etat_civil").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Marié") {
        $("#div_conjoint").show();
    } else {
        $("#div_conjoint").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: try,
    $("#etat_civil").on('change',function () {
        if (this.value == "Marié") {
            $("#div_conjoint").show();
        } else {
            $("#div_conjoint").hide();
        }
    });

Comment: I already test that , but didn't work

Comment: Seems link you need to put condition onReadyDocument which will execute it on load, simply put this 'if ($(this).val() == "Marié") {
        $("#div_conjoint").show();
    } else {
        $("#div_conjoint").hide();
    }' outside the on change method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the **old('field')** value for it is set then you can set your element to be visible.

For example, you can do something like this.

```
<input type="text" name="my-field" value="abc" style="display: {{ old('field') ? 'block' : 'none' }}">
```

By doing this you are checking if **old('field')** is set then the field/block/div should be visible otherwise keep it hidden.

So in your case when the validation fails and it redirects you back to the form you will have **old('field')** value set and the element should be visible to you.

**Update:**

As suggested by other guys you can also do this by putting the JS code on page *onload* but I don't prefer that way as it sometimes shows a slight delay in loading the element. Not a great deal but I still prefer doing it the other way that I explained above.